# Dimension of Skewness in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

Can someone help me how to solve this.

```
grayImage=dicomread('028tm.R.dcm');
sx=32;
sy=32;
theta=[0 pi/4 2*pi/4 3*pi/4 4*pi/4 5*pi/4 6*pi/4 7*pi/4];

gamma=1;
psi=0;
sigma=6; % ????12
lambda=[5 6 7 8 9 7];

# Creating 40 Gabor Filters
G = cell(5,8);
for i = 1:5
  for j = 1:8
    G{i,j}=zeros(65,65);
  end
end
for i = 1:5
  for j = 1:8
    f=1/lambda(i);      

    [T,gabout] = gaborfilter1(grayImage,sx,sy,f,theta(j));
    u{i,j}=mean2(gabout);
    del{i,j}=std2(gabout);  
    skew{i,j} =skewness(gabout);
    sk=[skew{:,:}];
    std=[u{:,:}];
    mn=[del{:,:}];
    disp(sk)             
  end
end
```

and this is I will show my workspace.

```
mn <1x40 double>
sk<1x10280 double>
std<1x40 double>
```

why sk(the value of skewness) is `1X10280` double????? it should be `1x40` like standard deviation and mean. How to make sk(skewness) to be `1x40`?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: I imagine it's because `mean2` and `std2` return scalars, whereas `skewness` returns a vector. What is the horizontal dimension of `grayImage`? It's not 257 pixels by any chance?

Comment: horizontal dimension? do you mean the size of grayImage? grayImage: <236x257 uint16>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `mean2` and `std2` operate on the entire image, but `skewness` operates on the *columns* of the image. You should define a new function

```
function sk = skewness2(X)
    sk = skewness(X(:));
end
```

And use that in place of `skewness`.